# Advice on programming a webpage where user input displays a selected image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am looking into setting up a basic website that displays a simple selection criteria (1 drop down box, 2 radio buttons sets) when the submit button is clicked it opens up a pop up window that displays an image whose location is specified by the selection criteria. This image is being updated at random so the pop-up needs to refresh or at least get and display the new image about every minute.

I have set up a simple html site (see below) that displays the image, located on my machine and refreshes every 30 seconds.

```
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
    <title>
    Real Time Image Display
    </title>
    <style>
     #geo img {
     max-width:100%; 
     max-height:100%;
     margin:auto;
     display:inline-block;
     vertical-align: middle;
     background-size: cover;
     }
    </style>
 </head>
 <body bgcolor=#00336>
    <div id="geo">
    <img src="file:///fileLocation/image.png" height="300" width="550"  alt=""> 
    </div>
</body>
```

I don't believe this is the best way to do this nor have I been able to figure out how to accomplish my original mission using this solution since I am unsure how to pass the selection criteria to these simple html sites to point them to the right image.

Any ideas on where I can look or what I can do?

Comment: for starters get rid of `file://` protocol and use web path to image ... can be relative and still work in file protocol for page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to add an ID tag to your image:

```
<img src="file:///fileLocation/image.png" id="imageToChange" height="300" width="550"  alt="">
```

Then you can use JavaScript to change the image, with no need for a refresh:

```
function changeImage() {
document.getElementById("imageToChange").src = "/newimage.png";
}
```

That's the basic of it anyway.  It should be noted that your image should not be pulled from the local file system, the way you have it now.  It needs to be on the server.

Here is an incredibly simple fiddle to show how this works:
https://jsfiddle.net/durbnpoisn/r7fk8ubz/

Comment: Right it would be I'm just testing things on my local machine right now and haven't group everything together properly. If have this set up as a javascript function could I pass the information from the original website via POST?

Comment: Yes.  But handling a POST in JavaScript is no fun.  You'd be better off intercepting it server side (like $imagIs=$_POST["img"]) then have JavaScript use that as imageIs = '<?echo $imagIs ?>'

Comment: Do you have a website that reviews that kind of thing I'm just not catching on to what you mean. Also for the code that you previously posted does it only refresh the image if it has a different name?

Comment: It doesn't refresh it.  It explicitly sets it to that.  It changes the source.  So whatever image you have at that ID will be changed to whatever image you tell it to.  Probably the most common usage for something like this would be a mouse rollover.  Do a view-source on this page:  http://buildmysite.dpoisn.com/

Comment: Check the answer again.  I added a spiffy little code example.

Comment: Thanks, that gave me an idea of how to properly implement everything.

Comment: Eggesllent!  I thought that would help.